# How to parse data (Observable) returned by valueChanges() on Firebase and plot to Chart.js

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve some data from Firebase RealTime Database, I'm being able to plot the data that I'm retrieving, but I don't know how to parse this data received as an Observable, to a list that I could plot on Chart.js or any other chart framework.

```
Here is my datastored.ts module 

<pre>
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavParams, DateTime } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { NavController, Item } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat';
    import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

    @IonicPage({
      name: 'DatastoredPage'
    })
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-datastored',
      templateUrl: 'datastored.html',
    })

    export class DatastoredPage {
      myDateStart:string = "2018-10-04"
      myDateEnd:string = "2018-10-30"
      incubator30: Observable<any[]>;  

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private db:AngularFireDatabase) {

        this.incubator30 = db.list('NeoSilence/Incubator1', ref => ref.orderByChild("d").startAt(this.myDateStart).endAt(this.myDateEnd)).valueChanges();    
      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad DatastoredPage');
        console.log(this.incubator30);
      }  
      getstartByDate() {
        console.log(this.myDateStart);
        console.log("Before the Startdate filter");
        this.incubator30 = this.db.list('NeoSilence/Incubator1', ref => ref.orderByChild("d").startAt(this.myDateStart).endAt(this.myDateEnd)).valueChanges();
        console.log("After the Startdate filter");
        this.incubator30.forEach(element => {
          element.forEach(co => {
            console.log(co.d)        
          })
        });
      }

      getendByDate() {
        console.log(this.myDateEnd);
        console.log("Before the Enddate filter");
        this.incubator30 = this.db.list('NeoSilence/Incubator1', ref => ref.orderByChild("d").startAt(this.myDateStart).endAt(this.myDateEnd)).valueChanges();
        console.log("After the Enddate filter");
        this.incubator30.forEach(element => {
          element.forEach(co => {
            console.log(co.d)
          })
        });
      }  
    }
    </pre>
```

And here is my HTML code where I'm being able to display that data retrieved.

```
    class="bgstyle" *ngFor="let StoredData of incubator30 | async">
    {{StoredData.d | json}} - {{StoredData.t | json}} {{StoredData.f | json}}dBA
```

How on the datastored.ts module I'll be able to read the information I want (date(d) and measurement(f) into a variable that I can plot on chart.js or highchart, or any other chart platform. [image]

Comment: You can convert Observable to array which you can use as data feed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, subscribing to the variable I'll would like to plot. Which as 'd' and 'f'.

```
this.incubator30.subscribe((res) => {
        this.date = res.map((value) => { return value.d });
        this.list = res.map((value) => { return value.f      

      })
```

Thanks.